# How to get values selectively from python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I read a JSON file and created a dictionary and trying to make a properties file with `key=value` format with just couple of attributes (`found` and `location`) from it. From below dictionary, I need to create a file with content

```
found=bike.tar.gz
location=china
```

Content of the dictionary below, it will be in same format and will have only one "found" item always.

```
>>> pprint(zdict)
{
 'found': {
    'bike.tar.gz': {
           'imported': False,
           'used': True,
           'location': 'china'
            }
     }
}
```

I tried:

```
>>> dict(list(zdict.values())[0]).keys()
dict_keys(['bike.tar.gz'])
```

couldn't move beyond this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complex part is to get the key value, since it's a special case: there is one key as a value of the dictionary. So convert to list and take the first element.

Then use this key to find the location.

```
zdict = {
 'found': {
    'bike.tar.gz': {
           'imported': False,
           'used': True,
           'location': 'china'
            }
     }
}

bike = list(zdict["found"])[0]
print("found={}".format(bike))
print("location={}".format(zdict["found"][bike]["location"]))
```

prints:

```
found=bike.tar.gz
location=china
```

but this format is probably designed to have several dicts under the "found" key, so use a loop to print them all (also works with your example and avoids to crash if the list is empty):

```
for bike,items in zdict["found"].items():
    print("found={}".format(bike))
    print("location={}".format(items["location"]))
```